# Why doesn't std::setbase(2) switch to binary output?

Tags: c++, radix, ostream, std, iomanip

[The cppreference page on `std::setbase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setbase) says:

> Values of base other than 8, 10, or 16 reset basefield to zero, which corresponds to decimal output and prefix-dependent input.

How come?

Is there a particular reason why only these bases are supported? It seems trivial to support at least anything up to 16 (actually, up to 36: 0-9 and then a-z) without having to make any sort of difficult choices. Specifically, 2 is a popular base, I would think there should be interest in `std::setbase(2)` (and a corresponding `std::binary`).

I can obviously print my own bits but it would have been nice for my ostream to do it.

Comment: the nice way to print binary is http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/operator_ltltgtgt2

Comment: @Cubbi: That is nice, but it requires the code printing to the stream to be aware of the need to print in binary. I want the _stream_ to convert to binary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only sure answer is "because the standard says so".

That being said, the standard mostly formalized the pre-standard iostream implementations, many of which probably were designed just to reach feature parity with `printf`, which supports only decimal, octal and hexadecimal (through ad-hoc, not-really-general syntax).

Also, as it is now it wouldn't be trivial to patch the iostream API to support "many" bases, given that the base setting ends up into a bitfield, not in a separate "current base" field.

Now, the standard requires `fmtflags` to be of some "bitmask type" - which may even be a `std::bitset`, so you may find a way to shovel all those new "base" fields somehow - but is it really worth the effort (plus the risk of breaking the code that assumes that `fmtflags` is of an integral type) for a feature that almost nobody really cares about?

So, to sum it up: bad initial design (like the rest of iostream, actually), nontrivial fix and no real user demand for such a feature.

Answer (score 5):

To the best of my knowledge there was no proposal to add support for binary (base 2) formatting to iostreams (see also [Has there been a proposal to add std::bin to the c++ standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41359232/has-there-been-a-proposal-to-add-stdbin-to-the-c-standard)). However, it is supported in C++20 [`std::format`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format):

```cpp
std::string s = std::format("{:b}", 42);
```

`std::format` is not widely available but you can use [the {fmt} library](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt), `std::format` is based on, in the meantime:

```cpp
std::string s = fmt::format("{:b}", 42);
```

**Disclaimer**: I'm the author of {fmt} and C++20 `std::format`.