# Converting a decimal number to binary in c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

this code finds the binary of a decimal integer N; it divides the number by 2 and takes the floor of the result and divides it also by 2,
the code gets the remainder of those divisions 0 or 1 and builds up the binary.

The problem with this code is that it won't run until the last division example (take 128 the last division is 1/2 and remainder is 1, the program stops at `N/2 > 0` as specified in the while loop and `1/2 = 0` since 1 is of type int).

How do I resolve this issue or how do I modify the condition in the while loop?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void ConvertToBinary(int N);
int main()
{
    int N = 1;
    while (1)
    {
        cout << "enter N: ";
        cin >> N;
        cout << endl;
        ConvertToBinary(N);
        cout << endl;
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
void ConvertToBinary(int N)
{
    int A[1000];
    int i=0;
    cout << "The binary of " << N << "= ";
    while (N / 2 > 0)
    {
        if (N % 2 == 0)
        {
            A[i] = 0;
        }
        else if (N % 2 != 0)
        {
            A[i] = 1;
        }
        N = N / 2;
        i++;
    }
    for (int j= i-1 ; j>=0 ; j--)
    {
        cout<<A[j];
    }


    cout << endl;

}
```

Comment: `while (N)` should do it, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`N` is not "a decimal integer". It is a *number*.

If you really want to talk specifics, it's already stored in binary.

What you're talking about is *representation*. What is the *representation* of the number when printed to screen? IOStreams by default will show you numbers in decimal.

You can use I/O Manipulators, though, to choose hexadecimal or octal instead. Sadly [there isn't a `std::bin` yet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41359232/560648), but we can use `std::bitset` for the same purpose:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <bitset>

int main()
{
    int x = 42;
    std::cout << x << '\n';
    std::cout << std::hex << x << '\n';
    std::cout << std::oct << x << '\n';
    std::cout << std::bitset<sizeof(x)>(x) << '\n';
}

// Output:
//   42
//   2a
//   52
//   1010
```

#### ([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/01a66b2985b62f1e))

And your whole approach (to "fake" a representation shift by changing your number to another number that happens to look like the binary representation of the original number when you print it in decimal representation — phew!) becomes obsolete, solving your problem effortlessly.